# How to Remove Code Duplicates in Below Methods

Tags: javascript

```
$("#threeToThree").click(function() {
  playSound("Start");
  executeTimer();
  var nextColor = arrangeThreeToThreeColors();

  $("#grid .btn").click(function() {
    animatePress(this);
    if ($(this).attr("id") === nextColor) {
      playSound("Success");
      totalPoint += 10;
      console.log("Total Point: " + totalPoint);
      seenColors = [];
      nextColor = arrangeThreeToThreeColors();
  } else {
      playSound("Failure");
}
});
});

$("#fourToFour").click(function() {
  playSound("Start");
  executeTimer();
  var nextColor = arrangeFourToFourColors();

  $("#grid .btn").click(function() {
   animatePress(this);
   if ($(this).attr("id") === nextColor) {
     playSound("Success");
     totalPoint += 10;
     console.log("Total Point: " + totalPoint);
     seenColors = [];
     nextColor = arrangeFourToFourColors();
} else {
  playSound("Failure");
}
});
});

$("#fiveToFive").click(function() {
  playSound("Start");
  executeTimer();
  var nextColor = arrangeFiveToFiveColors();

  $("#grid .btn").click(function() {
   animatePress(this);
   if ($(this).attr("id") === nextColor) {
     playSound("Success");
     totalPoint += 10;
     console.log("Total Point: " + totalPoint);
     seenColors = [];
     nextColor = arrangeFiveToFiveColors();
}  else {
     playSound("Failure");
}
});
});

function arrangeThreeToThreeColors() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
  let mod = i % 5;
   if (mod === 0 || mod === 1 || mod === 2) {
    var randomColor = getValidColor();
    manipulateButtons(i, randomColor);
    seenColors.push(randomColor);

} else {
  continue;
    }
    }
   var nextColor = getRandomColor(seenColors);
   $("#next").attr("class", "btn next " + nextColor);
   return nextColor;
    }

function arrangeFourToFourColors() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 18; i++) {
   let mod = i % 5;
   if (mod === 0 || mod === 1 || mod === 2 || mod === 3) {
     var randomColor = getValidColor();
     manipulateButtons(i, randomColor);
     seenColors.push(randomColor);

} else {
  continue;
   }
  }
 var nextColor = getRandomColor(seenColors);
 $("#next").attr("class", "btn next " + nextColor);
 return nextColor;
 }

function arrangeFiveToFiveColors() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
   var randomColor = getValidColor();
   manipulateButtons(i, randomColor);
   seenColors.push(randomColor);
 }
   var nextColor = getRandomColor(seenColors);
   $("#next").attr("class", "btn next " + nextColor);
   return nextColor;
 }
```

How can I make this code clear code? What is the best way to make this code more readable? Is there a way to implement #threeToThree.click(), #fourToFour.click() and #fiveToFive.click() contents in only one method? And can I combine the contents of arrangeThreeToThreeColors(), arrangeFourToFourColors(), arrangeFiveToFiveColors() in one method?

Answer (score 1):

Added Comments along the code update, take what part of the code refactor best suits you and you can ignore the reset or modify as you want.

### 1. Using Constants insted of string

```
const SoundStatus = {
    Start: "Start",
    Success: "Success",
    Failure: "Failure"
};
```

### 2. Global variables and using single point of update.

Single point update, would seem too much for simple update. But this will helpful when debugging, as you would know where the variables gets updated.

```
/**
 * I couldn't get the context of these 2 variables; assuming them to be global variables
 */

let seenColors = [];
let totalPoint = 0;

/**
 * Using Single setter to update global variables; With this it will be easier to track there changes
 */

function UpdateTotalPoint() {
    totalPoint += 10;
}

function ResetSeenColors() {
    seenColors = [];
}

function UpdateSeenColors(color) {
    seenColors.push(color);
}
```

### 3. Removing Duplicate code

```
/**
 * Abstract attribute update to single function
 */

function updateNextAttribute() {
    let nextColor = getRandomColor(seenColors);
    $("#next").attr("class", "btn next " + nextColor);
    return nextColor;
}


function ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(value) {
    const randomColor = getValidColor();
    manipulateButtons(value, randomColor);
    UpdateSeenColors(randomColor);
}

/**
 * Remove contiune on else, as there is no statements to be executed of that; Its understood 
 */

function arrangeFiveToFiveColors() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
        ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(i);
    }
    return updateNextAttribute();
}

function arrangeFourToFourColors() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 18; i++) {
        let mod = i % 5;
        if (mod === 0 || mod === 1 || mod === 2 || mod === 3) {
            ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(i);
        }
    }
    return updateNextAttribute();
}

function arrangeThreeToThreeColors() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        let mod = i % 5;
        if (mod === 0 || mod === 1 || mod === 2) {
            ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(i);
        }
    }
    return updateNextAttribute();
}

/**
 * Grid Updation
 * arrangeColor; will be arrangeThreeToThreeColors, arrangeFourToFourColors or arrangeFiveToFiveColors
 * 
 */

function AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeColor, context) {
    $("#grid .btn").click(function () {
        animatePress(context);
        if ($(context).attr("id") === nextColor) {
            playSound(SoundStatus.Success);
            UpdateTotalPoint();
            console.log("Total Point: " + totalPoint);
            ResetSeenColors();
            nextColor = arrangeColor();
        } else {
            playSound(SoundStatus.Failure);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Updating click listiner of 3-3, 4-4 & 5-5
 */

$("#threeToThree").click(function () {
    initilize();
    const nextColor = arrangeThreeToThreeColors();
    AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeThreeToThreeColors, this);
});

$("#fourToFour").click(function () {
    initilize();
    const nextColor = arrangeFourToFourColors();
    AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeFourToFourColors, this);
});

$("#fiveToFive").click(function () {
    initilize();
    const nextColor = arrangeFiveToFiveColors();
    AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeFiveToFiveColors, this);
});

/**
 * Abstracting inital Start sound and executeTimer
 */

function initilize() {
    playSound(SoundStatus.Start);
    executeTimer();
}
```

### Final code after Refactoring

```
const SoundStatus = {
    Start: "Start",
    Success: "Success",
    Failure: "Failure"
};

let seenColors = [];
let totalPoint = 0;

function updateTotalPoint() {
    totalPoint += 10;
}

function resetSeenColors() {
    seenColors = [];
}

function updateSeenColors(color) {
    seenColors.push(color);
}

function updateNextAttribute() {
    let nextColor = getRandomColor(seenColors);
    $("#next").attr("class", "btn next " + nextColor);
    return nextColor;
}

function ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(value) {
    const randomColor = getValidColor();
    manipulateButtons(value, randomColor);
    updateSeenColors(randomColor);
}

function arrangeFiveToFiveColors() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
        ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(i);
    }
    return updateNextAttribute();
}

function arrangeFourToFourColors() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 18; i++) {
        let mod = i % 5;
        if (mod === 0 || mod === 1 || mod === 2 || mod === 3) {
            ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(i);
        }
    }
    return updateNextAttribute();
}

function arrangeThreeToThreeColors() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        let mod = i % 5;
        if (mod === 0 || mod === 1 || mod === 2) {
            ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue(i);
        }
    }
    return updateNextAttribute();
}

function AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeColor, context) {
    $("#grid .btn").click(function () {
        animatePress(context);
        if ($(context).attr("id") === nextColor) {
            playSound(SoundStatus.Success);
            updateTotalPoint();
            console.log("Total Point: " + totalPoint);
            resetSeenColors();
            nextColor = arrangeColor();
        } else {
            playSound(SoundStatus.Failure);
        }
    });
}

$("#threeToThree").click(function () {
    initilize();
    const nextColor = arrangeThreeToThreeColors();
    AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeThreeToThreeColors, this);
});

$("#fourToFour").click(function () {
    initilize();
    const nextColor = arrangeFourToFourColors();
    AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeFourToFourColors, this);
});

$("#fiveToFive").click(function () {
    initilize();
    const nextColor = arrangeFiveToFiveColors();
    AnimateGridButton(nextColor, arrangeFiveToFiveColors, this);
});

function initilize() {
    playSound(SoundStatus.Start);
    executeTimer();
}
```

After all the possible abstraction, we are left with code that is specific for each functions; except for `ManipulateButtonAndUpdateSeenColorsWithRandomValue` (Please come up with a proper name, that would fit the requirment). Couple of lines of abstraction is still possible for `arrageColor` related functions. Since I don't have a full picture of your requirement, I would leave that to you.